# Как сделать настройки для команды в дискорд

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord

Создаю своего бота для дискорда, но не понимаю как можно создать чтобы так появлялась настройка (message) [image: Настройка для команды бота]

буду благодарна за пример кода..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опять же слеш-команды. [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1553626/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5) я описал, как установить `py-cord`, поэтому здесь приведу только код с описанием.

```
from discord import Option
...
@bot.slash_command(name="wew", description='Описание команды')
async def wew(ctx, foo: Option(str, #тип данных ввода
                                 name='роль', #имя опции (необязательно)
                                 description='Bar', #описание опции
                                 required=True))): #обязательность введения параметра для команды
    pass
```

Подробнее читайте [тут](https://guide.pycord.dev/interactions/application-commands/slash-commands)